# Basic haskell program to find a string inside a file

Tags: haskell

This is my first Haskell attempt so my understanding is fairly limited. I wanted to write a very basic program to check if a file contains the word `ERROR`. I came up with the following which of course doesn't even compile.

```
 import Text.Regex.Posix

 containsErrorString :: String -> Bool
 containsErrorString x = x =~ "ERROR" :: Bool

 fileContainsErrorString fileName = do
    s <- readFile fileName
    containsErrorString s
```

Is this the right approach and if not what would be the correct way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A light rewrite**

I suggest:

1. Use `Text` instead of `String` for any "serious" work.
2. If you don't need regex, don't use regex.

In code:

```
import Data.Text as T

containsErrorString :: Text -> Bool
containsErrorString = ("ERROR" `T.isInfixOf`)

fileContainsErrorString :: FilePath -> IO Bool
fileContainsErrorString = containsErrorString `fmap` T.readFile

-- Warning, code typed and not tested.
```

**Your Code**

There isn't anything wrong with your approach.  The use of `String` remains common and perfectly acceptable for most uses.  Your error is just that you forgot to `return` the result (you are in a monad, `IO`, and `containsErrorString` is a pure function).

Instead of:

```
containsErrorString s
```

you should have had:

```
return (containsErrorString s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Main problem is in fact that  `fileContainsErrorString :: IO Bool`,

but `containsErrorString (s:: String) ::  Bool`.

So, you need to wrap `containsErrorString` into `IO`, for example use `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`

```
fileContainsErrorString fileName = do
    s <- readFile fileName
    return $ containsErrorString s
```